# Codename One List Containing Lists

Tags: java, list, user-interface, nested, codenameone

Note: anywhere I refer to a `List` in this question, I am talking about `com.codename1.ui.List`.

Can I use Codename One's GUI Designer to put a `List` in a `List` and then populate each sub-list with its own data?

I can define a `Container` in the GUI Designer and put a `List` in it (I'll call it InnerList) then set the `Container` as the `Renderer` for another `List` (I'll call this one OuterList.) What I have been unable to do is to then set the data for the InnerList in a particular cell of OuterList. When I modify OuterList's `ListItems` in the GUI, InnerList doesn't even appear in the list of keys, and I have not found a way to populate InnerList from code either.

To work around this problem, I have had to define two user classes implementing `ListCellRenderer` (and extending `Container`) and, in code, set them as the renderers for OuterList and InnerList, respectively. In the GUI Designer, there is only OuterList with no apparent `Renderer`. This works, but it doesn't really fit in with the way the rest of the GUI is defined and it adds confusion.

Comment: What Language and GUI framework are you using?

Comment: The language is Java and the GUI framework is Codename One.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

This wouldn't make any sense. Codename One list renderer's are "rubber stamps" which means they have no state and so you will not be able to vary the size of the elements or access individual components within them. What you need to do is use a Component->Container hierarchy to achieve the functionality you are seeking.

Comment: Do you mean that it wouldn't make sense to put a List in a List?

Comment: Yes, nesting lists wouldn't make sense.